# jQuery scrollTop website jumps halfway down on page load

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, scrollto

I'm in the process of designing a new online portfolio for myself and thus far all had been going pretty smoothly. It's a single HTML5 file broken into separate 'articles', each of which contains a skill, through which the user navigates via `<a href="#target">` links. To smooth this out, I've used two chunks of jQuery, one that works in IE and one for everything else. ;-)

However, after only a little fiddling around today I've encountered a strange bug whereby once the page has loaded, it appears to jump to around halfway down. In Google Chrome it then jerkily returns to the top, but in Firefox 4 and Internet Explorer 8 it stays put, nowhere near the page's intended origin.

Please take a look for yourself at: [my online portfolio to be](http://www.chrisphilpot.co.uk/html5/).

All I had been doing this morning was adjusting CSS, which I have isolated as not being the issue. What's more, commenting out lines 216–27 of the HTML file to remove the page scrolling plugins also fails to resolve the issue.

However, removing the reference to the main jQuery library (`<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>`, line 202) does remove the jumping bug... as well as all of the other jQuery-based page functionality! Dang!

Any bright ideas? I was pretty close to completing the site and am tearing my hair out now such a silly bug seems to be standing in its way.

Comment: It's probably best to just remove the `.focus()` since it's in a section at the bottom of the page. It's not a search box or a login form, so it's really not necessary.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree - having fiddled for half an hour I'm perfectly happy with how the page is now functioning. Thanks for your reassurance. :-)

Answer (score 1):

(Question answered in the comments. Converted to a community wiki post. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I've had a breakthrough: I noticed something about where the page was jumping to each time: the very bottom of the browser window displayed the first of my Ajax form fields `(<input type="text" ... id="senderName" ... />`, line 138) and removing the `$('#senderName').focus();` instruction from the appropriate .js file has solved the issue insomuch as the page no longer jumps. However, this is with the obvious loss of the first form field being focused when the user scrolls to that point on the page.
>
> Can anyone recommend a good coding compromise between these two states?

@drudge wrote:

> It's probably best to just remove the .focus() since it's in a section at the bottom of the page. It's not a search box or a login form, so it's really not necessary.

The OP wrote:

> I'm inclined to agree - having fiddled for half an hour I'm perfectly happy with how the page is now functioning. Thanks for your reassurance. :-)

Comment: You don't get rep for it, but here's +1 for putting the answer in an answer.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Thanks. The +1 moves the question from the "unanswered question" queue, so it was worth doing.